# Need advice in implementing ASP.NET custom output cache

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, caching

My website is similar like blog where page content will not change frequently. So i decided to to use page output cache.

But when i turned it on output cache for every page and set the cache duration for 1 hour, my web-hosting provided suspended my site as it is using extensive system memory. After that i re-set the duration to 2 mins, but some times i'm getting database connection timeout errors.

For better performance, anyway i need to caching, but not to cache in the memory. so i came with following idea. please advice whether it is best approach or have any better solutions than this?

I want to write HTTP Module where it intercept all requests. If cache version for specific request is not there, then it writes the page response (using filters write) to disk as file, otherwise sends this file as response.

target framework is 2.0

Comment: Try taking a look at [the Microsoft Enterprise Library](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff648951.aspx). There's a Caching Application Block that may solve your problem.

Comment: @Koen, i hope that is only for data caching, not for output caching

Answer (score 0):

If you're in ASP.NET 4.0, then you don't need to write this as a HttpModule - output caching is provider-based, you can just write a new provider and plug it in. Gunnar Peipman has a great blog [here](http://weblogs.asp.net/gunnarpeipman/archive/2009/11/19/asp-net-4-0-writing-custom-output-cache-providers.aspx) on writing a file-based output cache provider.